# When add new model to database has error Cannot insert duplicate key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, primary-key

When i want add new model to DB

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Factors'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Factors'. The duplicate key value is (1001).
The statement has been terminated.
```

My code :

```
var factor = new Factor();
factor.UserId = UserId;
Db.Factors.Add(factor);
Db.SaveChanges();
```

And model map:

[image]

In my design factor is must start whit 1000 and my code for this :

```
protected override void Seed(BreDbContext context)
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT('Factors', RESEED, 1000);");          
}
```

Comment: this is becuase same id is assign to event modal that why db throw error

Comment: you mean Baskets?

Comment: On insert you do not need to set the id, this will be set by the database

Comment: I know ,i don't set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Find solution.

Description for problem

When run below code in Migration Seed

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT('Factors', RESEED, 1000);");
```

this code run per request and this code destroy database.
Remove this code and insert below code

```
protected override void Seed(BreDbContext context)
{
    //context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT('Factors', RESEED, 1000);");  
    for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++)
    {
        context.factors.add(new factor());
    }
    context.savechanges();
    var rang = context.factors.tolist();
    context.factors.removerange(rang);
    context.savechanges();  
}
```

after create database comment all code in seed method.

best reference https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Mar/26/Firing-an-Entity-Framework-Database-Initializer-from-within-DbContext

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because u insert the value that has already in the PRIMARY KEY field which mean PRIMARY KEY value must be a unique value

For example u have a table with value :

```
id name
1 john
2 serah
3 crish
```

But after that you insert a new value:

```
3 victoria
```

in above case will throw an error because in the table already has a value with id = 3 (crish) // id field is unique (PRIMARY KEY)

OR

In other problem case if ur table has a relation with other table, if u want to insert a new value into FOREIGN KEY Table, u need to inserted first in PRIMARY KEY Table because FOREIGN KEY need to reference to PRIMARY KEY value.
I hope my answer helping u

Comment: Tnx for answering. But id set by the database

Comment: what table u insert a value ? into PK table or FK table ? @HadiJahangiri

Comment: in the code section u post " factor.UserId = UserId; ", what value in "UserId" variable ? and please "SELECT * FROM ur table" to ensure u not insert the same key

Comment: UserId = post data user id, Generate key by database not me

Comment: Whether UserId is PK in ur table?